# 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know  this question has been asked before.So I have checked that post in stackoverflow and  followed the suggestions there.Problem not solved.I have  reference to the System.Data and to System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Entity.Design.the problem persists.I get this error

The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Comment: Is the Entity Framework NuGet package installed for the project?

Comment: Yes I installed it

Comment: Could you share the content of your `.csproj` file?

Comment: I am sorry Riwen.. I am a complete newbie .where  is this file